# Eigenfaces in OpenCV using C++

Tags: c++, opencv, pca

I have written a code to create eigenfaces. I have taken 3 images of different people as input. I have calculated the eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Since only 3 images are taken, I select all the three eigenvectors, each of size 36000x1, as the principal components. When I reshape the eigenvectors to see the image, I get eigenface for only one person. The other images are almost completely blank.

I am extracting each eigenvector from covevec(matrix of eigenvectors of covariance matrix)

```
col1=covevec.col(0);
col2=covevec.col(1);
col3=covevec.col(2);
```

I reshape them as follows:

```
if (!col1.isContinuous() && !col2.isContinuous() && !col3.isContinuous())
{
    col1=col1.clone();
    col2=col2.clone();
    col3=col3.clone();
}
Mat final1,final2,final3;
final1=col1.reshape(0,200);
final2=col2.reshape(0,200);
final3=col3.reshape(0,200);
```

This how final2 looks like:
[image: Output image final2]

And the other two look like this:[image: Output image final1]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need much more data, also you have to normalize() your images before the pca step

Comment: Yea....increasing the data worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine, so what is wrong?

DataDataData, it's so crucial when performing computer vision tasks like this. To give yourself an advantage use a readily avaliable dataset with corresponding test data - [This would work](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ecdecoro/eigenfaces/)

Also, as berak says normalising the images will help. In [Turk & Pentland](http://www.vision.jhu.edu/teaching/vision08/Handouts/case_study_pca1.pdf) (Which if you haven't read you should) they state:

> Step 6.3: compute the M best eigenvectors of AAT : ui = Avi
>
> (important: normalize ui such that ||ui|| = 1)

This will mean that all your training data will be of the same vein and give your algorithm much better chance of success